# Angular $Scope structure overridden by JSON object

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have created a Angular controller which has the following structure

```
 function CustomerViewModel($scope,$http) 
    {
            var str = '{ "Name": "Shiv", "Salary": "1000", "Color": ""}';

    }
```

I am making a JSON call using $http and setting the customer data. But the JSON data coming from server does not have Color property. This property is calculated by the viewmodel. So the complete "Customer" structure of viewmodel is overridden.

I know we can set property by property but would like to what is the best practice to achieve it.

Comment: you can use angular.extend
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend

Comment: Thank @DayanMorenoLeon that worked. Do nt know how to vote a comment as answer.

Comment: there i made it an answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

you can use angular.extend

docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend

Answer (score 0):

U could use concat() method to do that. for exmaple. See If this could help.

**Example Code:**

```
$scope.old = [{"Name": "Shiv", "Salary": "1000"}];
$scope.new = [
    {"Color": ""},
];
$scope.new = $scope.new.concat($scope.old);
```

Comment: Thanks @Vaibhav for the answer will test it Dayan's solution worked for me.